# Is there a way to simplify this JavaScript code? (same functions for multiple classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, simplify

Hi the code I am trying to simplify is:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selection0').click(function() {
        $('.selection0').css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
    $('.selection1').click(function() {
        $('.selection1').css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
    $('.selection2').click(function() {
        $('.selection2').css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
    $('.selection3').click(function() {
        $('.selection3').css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
    $('.selection4').click(function() {
        $('.selection4').css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
  });
```

I feel like I must be missing something, and that there is a way to make this much cleaner. Thanks!

Edit: I just wanted to clarify the functionality of this code. Basically, each 'selection' class corresponds to span tags around sentences in a paragraph. The code allows the user to highlight exactly one sentence in each paragraph by clicking on it. If it clicks on a different sentence, that sentence will be highlighted while the rest of the sentences in that specific paragraph is deselected.

Comment: Can you show your HTML please?

Comment: @PeeHaa Here is some sample HTML code: <span class="selection1">Paragraph_1_Sentence_1</span><span class="selection1">Paragraph_1_Sentence_2</span> <br> <span class="selection2">Paragraph_2_Sentence_1</span><span class="selection2">Paragraph_2_Sentence_2</span>

Comment: @honeywind: if the `selection*` is the only class on the element. my edited code should work.

Comment: @honeywind I posted a fiddle the doesn't performs what you want to do.  By highlighting the clicked one and unhighlighting the others.

Comment: I've updated mine to reflect your updates...  I think you'll find it quite a bit simpler than @PeeHaa's answer, actually...

Comment: heads up, if you are intending each class to be a unique identifier, then it's better to use IDs...better performance when traversing the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selection0, .selection1, .selection2, .selection3, .selection4').click(function() {
        $('.'+$(this).attr('class')).css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
  });
```

Although it seems like that isnt what you are trying to do.

You first set background to white and then to yellow.

Although that's exactly what your code does

EDIT

Changed the first change of the background to represent all elements with the current class in stead of just the one clicked (thanks Sean).

The code expects the class to be the only class.

If you can show your code I will see whether this will work or I'll update my answer.

EDIT

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Dznp/

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing. Please note that this will only be the same if there is just one element with each class.

Comment: @Sean McMillan: What do you mean? Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Self & @Sean: I see what you mean now. Will update my anser. :)

Comment: `this` will be the element that was just clicked. If there are multiple elements with `class=selection1`, then the original would highlight them all when any of them are clicked, while using `this` will highlight only the clicked one. If the `selectionX` classes are applied to each cell in a grid row, the original code will highlight the whole row, while using `this` will highlight only one cell.

Comment: @Sean McMillan Right I've created multiple elements under each class, which explains why I cannot use $(this) in both lines.

Comment: @honeywind & @Sean: updated answer. Not sure what your HTML looks like though. So don't know if this is the good way to go.

Comment: @PeeHaa Woot your code does the trick! And avoids the inefficient for-loop. Thanks so much, this is exactly was I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to have a single class and have the following code :

```
$('.selection').click(function() {        
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white').css('background-color', 'yellow');    
});
```

Seems like odd code, though...  I'm guessing your just wanting it to flash when you click it?

EDIT to Add :  Remember, you can have more than one class on an object...  ie `<div class="selection selection1>` etc...

EDIT 2 :

From your update and posted HTML, make all of your spans have the same class and use this :

```
$('.selection').click(function() {            
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow').siblings().css('background-color', 'white');    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/9pF6U/

Comment: @ShaneBlake I wanted to let one sentence from each paragraph be highlighted, but this example only lets one sentence from all paragraphs to be highlighted.

Comment: @honeywind  Not if each paragraph is in a separate container, such as a `<p></p>` or `<div></div>`

Comment: @ShaneBlake That's true! Could you tell me why this is?

Comment: @honeywind  It's `.siblings()`...  Any elements inside other parents are not going to be siblings...  I updated the jsFiddle linked above to work like this...

Comment: @ShaneBlake Thanks I have yet to learn about .siblings(). I've already accepted PeeHaa's answer, but I've given you an upvote for showing me this simpler code and your kind help. Thanks again Shane. =)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you give all the elements the same class? The way you are naming the classes makes them all seem like ids to me.  Give them all a class of selection and just do

```
$('.selection').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    $('.selection').not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QfS3G/

Comment: I've added an edit to explain why I made these multiple classes.

Comment: @honeywind I understand your functionality better after your edit.  Try the updated code in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to toggle state of an element amongst a set.
If this assumption is correct you can use the snippet below:

```
var allItems = '.selection0, .selection1, .selection2, .selection3, .selection4';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(allItems).click(function() {
            $(allItems).css('background-color', 'white');
            $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
});
```

The code below is to correct the code that was posted in the question.

You can merge mutlitple selectors into a single set by seperating them with a comma.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selection0, .selection1, .selection2, .selection3, .selection4').click(function() {
            $('.selection0').css('background-color', 'white');
            $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Comma-separate all of your classes in the selector, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selection0, .selection1, .selection2').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was looking for in my situation, but this trick is good to know, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    $('.selection' + i).click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
}
```

Of course if you want to do different things for each, you could include a switch statement looking something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    $('.selection' + i).click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });

    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        // Do something here if we are .selection0
        break;

    case 1:
        // Do something here if we are .selection1
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('[class *= selection]').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/